How to draw a shaded area which tightly includes all the points in scatter plot?
I've pairs of y and z locations which I'm plotting as a scatter plot as shown below.

Looking at the plot, we can visualize a tight boundary which includes all of the points. My question is how do we draw this boundary in python? Ideally, I would like to have a filled region representing this area.
I've taken a look at scipy.spatial.ConvexHull, but it fails to capture the lower curve.
My attempt:
plt.scatter(yloc, zloc)

points = np.column_stack((yloc, zloc))
hull = ConvexHull(points)

for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'r-')


If you want to play with the data, it is available here. Y locations are under the header 'Points:1' and Z locations are under 'Points:2'.

Does alphashape help you (instead of convex hull)?

You need some sort of clear criterion for the shape. The example you shared is that of the tightest shape that's entirely convex. User Rob proposed alphashape, a parameterised shape with parameter alpha defined as the value a, such that an edge of a disk of radius 1/a can be drawn between any two edge members of a set of points and still contain all the points. But other rules are possible - what shape do you expect, and what is the rule that would lead to such a shape according to you?

I didn't know about alphashape; seems very useful in this case. However, I see that it draws piecewise linear boundaries. @Grismar, I'm expecting a downward moon crescent shape with preferably smoother outer lines. The rule of the tightest shape that's entirely convex is what I'm looking for, with an additional condition of having smoother lines if possible.

A crescent shape would be entire convex for the upper limb, but entire concave for the lower limb. You'd need some sort of envelope that allows you to specify where the rule changes. Having said that, to determine a concave hull (even for a section), you likely end up with something like alphashape anyway - is there a specific reason that doesn't meet your needs?

Thanks to the users for pointing me to alphashape. As the alphashape code provided by Keerthan draws piecewise linear boundaries, I wasn't completely satisfied with it. Here's how I managed to generate a smooth curve.
Continuing from Keerthan's answer
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev

# Instead of ax.add_path, extract the outer points

y = [i[0] for i in list(alpha_shape.exterior.coords)]
z = [i[1] for i in list(alpha_shape.exterior.coords)]

points = np.array([y, z])

# Create a parametric spline
# Value of s handles tradeoff between smoothness and accuracy.
tck, u = splprep(points, s=500, per=True)
u_new = np.linspace(0, 1, 300)
y_new, z_new = splev(u_new, tck)

plt.fill(y_new, z_new, linewidth=2, color='tab:red', alpha=0.5)

Result with s=500 (which favours smoothness at a loss of completely capturing all the points) is as follows:


Have you tried alphashape? Docs: https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import alphashape
from descartes import PolygonPatch

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.random.rand(15)
y = np.random.rand(15)

points = np.column_stack((x, y))
ax.scatter(x, y)

alpha = 0.5  # Adjust this value to capture the shape better
alpha_shape = alphashape.alphashape(points, alpha)
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(alpha_shape, alpha=alpha))

plt.show()


Alphashape seems to be very relevant to my case. However, I see that the outer boundaries are piecewise linear. Is there a way to draw a smooth curve from the outer points detected, rather than piecewise linear connections?
